# Transcendental equation

Tags: transcendental-equations

If $\alpha$ be a root of

> $x^{x-\sqrt{x}} = \sqrt{x}+1$.

**We need to find the value(s) of $(\alpha + \frac{1}{\alpha})$**. WolframAlpha shows two possible roots of the equation.[image]

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: We need to find a+1/a if a is root of the equation.

Comment: Hitting this with Mathematica's numerical techniques suggests that $\alpha + 1/\alpha \approx 3.0000...$ for the larger of the two roots, out to at least 100 decimal places. 
But I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: I tried converting it to a form suitable to use Lambert W Function by using $t = \sqrt{x} + 1$. The equation transformed into $t = e^{2(t-1)(t-2)ln(t-1)}$. But, I cannot proceed further with this.

Comment: In what context did this problem arise? Given what @Michael Seifert found, I would find it very amazing that you would have stumbled on this by randomly looking at various transcendental equations.

Comment: A friend of mine gave it to me. Don't know where he got it from.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert. Even with 5000 decimal places

Answer (score -1):

One solution of the equation is:

$x=\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Therefore

$\alpha+\frac{1}{\alpha}=3$.

Setting $\sqrt{x}+1=t$, the equation can be written as

$t=x^{x-\sqrt{x}}$.

We have an equivalence between two powers.

We know that two powers are equal if they have the same base and the same exponent, so we can assume for a moment that the base  $x=t$ and write:

$t=t^{x-\sqrt{x}}$.

This equality of powers implies that since they have the same base ($t$), they must have the same exponent:

$1=x-\sqrt{x}$.

Solving this equation we get

$x=\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Comment: “ We know that two powers are equal if they have the same base and the same exponent, so we can assume for a moment that the base =”

This logic is not working here.